# Как запустить выполнение программы на JAVA в Intellij IDEA по шагам?

Tags: intellij-idea

У меня есть набранный код и я хочу пошагово посмотреть, как он выполняется с отображением всех действий программы.

Comment: Используйте дебагер и ставьте точки остановки?

Answer (score 2):

Способов куча. Какие приходят на ум:

1. Сверху справа (по умолчанию) можно найти панельку с зеленым треугольником - простой запуск, и схематичным жуком - нужный вам запуск в режиме дебагинга.
2. Слева от строки `public static void main`есть треугольник, щелкнув по которому можно выбрать DEbugging и получить тот же результат
3. нажать shift+F9

Если вы еще ни разу не запускали программу, то 1 и 3 могут не работать, воспользуйтесь 2

Запустив в режиме дебагинга программа просто выполнится, елси вы не поставите точки остановки. Для этого надо кликнуть по пустой области чуть провее номера строки в редакторе, появится красная точка. Когда выполнение дойдет до этого места программа остановится и вы сможете пошагово ее выполнять дальше кнопками F7-F9 или соответсвующие им гуишными кнопками в окне дебага