# Пошаговое выполнение кода Java

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea

Только начинаю познавать язык Java. Возник вопрос по пошаговому выполнению кода в редакторе (IntelliJ).

Вопрос в следующем. Когда в VBA в редакторе пишется скрипт (к примеру, для автоматизации в браузере через Selenium), если возможность выполнить код по одной строке при помощи клавиши `F8`

Есть ли похожий прием в Java в редакторе IntelliJ? Чтобы можно было исполнить конкретный кусок кода без запуска всего проекта.

Спасибо.

Comment: Такое может быть только под отладкой. VBA скриптовый и, по-моему, не имел предварительной сборки в байткод, т.к. в реальном времени выполнялся построчно. А java - другое

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как запустить выполнение программы на JAVA в Intellij IDEA по шагам?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1087947/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%b0-java-%d0%b2-intellij-idea-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%bc)

Comment: Возможно поможет этот вопрос [Автотесты на Java Selenium. Среда разработки для отладки кода в режиме реального времени](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1155186/218971)